# Setting up dual monitors

Tags: workspace

I want to set up dual monitors to improve my workspace. So far, I'm planning to buy a cheap [Nvidia Geforce 9400 GT card](http://www.pcgameshardware.com/aid,657567/Geforce-9400-GT-reviewed/Reviews/) to make a [Samsung 2333SW 23-inch Widescreen Monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001P5CAV6) work together with my old 17-inch Samsung SyncMaster.

I usually work at a 1024x768 resolution on the syncmaster. So 2 questions:

a) Does the graphics card allow to set up a separate screen resolution for the widescreen monitor?

b) If not, wouldn't this look like crap due to the different screen ratios?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the Ewok Adventure.

Comment: I agree - see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/ for details of how to the join the beta - it's likely this question will be moved there shortly...

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the new site. Heh, please move this question.

Comment: dude, now I can't edit my own question =/

Comment: @dmindreader: Link your account and you will be able to edit it.

Comment: Already linked and I can't.

Comment: Ask for help on Meta.StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

If your display card has dual output, and (if windows) you chose to "extend desktop", then two monitors can have different resolution and ratio. One more interesting thing is, you can change the "virtual" position of the monitors.

If you do "cloning", then only one resolution is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes.

b) It will look crap anyway if you have two different size monitors side by side.

Comment: I disagree. I find it more important, that both monitors have the same   amount of pixel^2/inch, so the ratio and the size of the windows when moving from one monitor to the other is the same.

Comment: Yes, and good luck trying to find two different sized monitor which have the same amount of pixel density. I know EIZO monitors are, but those are expensive as hell.

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA Control Panel will allow you to manage the rotation and resolution for each of the monitors.  Display Properties in Windows will allow you to change the resolutions and placement.  All of these settings are done per-monitor and can be setup in many configurations.  Make sure you get the latest display drivers for your 9400 GT from [NVIDIA's website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) to ensure maximum compatibility.